# android plugin in eclipse lost after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, android, eclipse

Recently, i upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10, Eclipse also upgraded to Helios but android Plugin and projects are lost.what to do to restore them?

Comment: Not good, i think when you upgrade eclipse also upgraded and the old version and it's files has been deleted to install the new version

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Android plugin again. It is installed via Eclipse's plugin mechanism, not via Ubuntu package management machanism

See [Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and [Installing the ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)